# How to centralize an XSD schema for consumption by other projects/solutions?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, nuget, biztalk, azure-logic-apps

We have Biztalk solutions that we are moving to Logic Apps. We would like to be able to version control canonical schemas and centralize them using Nuget or a similar package-management strategy.

How do we "package" an `XSD` schema in a way that will allow us to reference it from other visual studio solutions?

From what I understand, when you create a Biztalk solution and build and deploy it, it will `GAC` all the artifacts.

**How do we mimic this functionality of *centralizing/packaging* the artifacts (such as the XSD canonical schema) to be reusable by other Logic Apps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this comes up with BizTalk Apps, my advice is...don't.  And so far, I've seen no reason the change that advice with Logic Apps.

So, you absolutely should store the official original schema in some source control, but each 'app' should maintain it's own internal copy of that schema.

In BizTalk Server and Azure Integration Accounts, there's nothing stopping you from deploying the same Schema multiple times.

In terms of LogicApps specifically, the Integration Account serves the same role as the GAC for BizTalk apps.

The reason to avoid referencing a 'central' schema in multiple apps is that creates a huge dependency between apps which may have little to do with each other beyond sharing some canonical resource.

So, it's important to define your app boundaries.  Meaning, the Purchasing App is totally different than the Warehouse App, but they may share some internal PO format and each app would have it's own copy of the internal PO, PO_warehouse & PO_purchasing.

For BizTalk, boundaries would be VS Solution -> .msi -> BizTalk Application.
For Logic Apps, VS Solution -> ARM Template(s) - Resource Group.

'Canonical' is a source code pattern only.  Also, the 'benefits' of 'canonical' resources are elusive and the dependencies it creates have always been a bigger problem.

Comment: thanks so much for your response. could you please clarify why is your advice to store the same schema locally for every app? how is this treated differently than any other resource such as a nuget package?

Comment: if we are in the course of active development against the canonical schema as well as logic apps, how do we manage updating the schema across all consumers of that schema?

Comment: additionally, how would the logic app know which version of the schema it needs? how does the developer *know* which version of the schema is being used by which solution?

Comment: doesn't this invalidate the notion of "canonical"? how it can be canonical if apps have different versions of the same "canonical" schema?